# how to load images used in elm code with webpack 2?

Tags: webpack-dev-server, elm, webpack-2

Suppose i have this view function:

```
view: Model -> Html Msg
view model = 
    img [ src "static/img/elm.jpg" ] []
```

**How to make sure webpack 2 knows about it and loads it inside the `dist` folder as expected?**

I found `elm-asssets-loader` package [here](https://github.com/NoRedInk/elm-assets-loader) - which is build for this scenario - but i don't understand how to use it.
my `webpack.config.js` is:

```
module: {
   rules: [
        ...
       {
           test: /\.elm$/,
            exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
            use: [{
                    loader: 'elm-hot-loader'
                  },
                  {
                      loader: 'elm-webpack-loader?verbose=true&warn=true&debug=true'
                  },
                  {
                      loader: 'elm-assets-loader?module=MyAssets&tagger=AssetPath'
                  },

            ]
        },


  ]
```

}

I've seen `elmAssetsLoader` and `fileLoader` custom functions mentioned inside the docks - but is not clear where to put them. I tried placing them inside `module.exports object`, inside `modules`, inside `plugins`.. every time i get this error:
`Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema...`

I also tried placing the `elm-assets-loader` before and after the `elm--webpack-loader`. When placed after `elm-webpack-loader` - i get an error inside the `Main.elm` file - which is wired because the `Main.elm` is just fine. Nothing wrong with it.

And when i place it before `elm-webpack-loader` absolutely nothing happens. Not even a warning message.

I also have the 2 modules as instructed:

```
-- module MyAssets exposing (..)
--
-- type AssetPath
--     = AssetPath String
--
-- elmImage : AssetPath
-- elmImage =
--     AssetPath "../static/img/elm.jpg" -- this is the location of my image, and it's correct.
--
```

and a view module with the image:

```
module View exposing (..)
view = 
   img [ src "what to put in here?" ] []
```

I'm new to webpack and that's probably why is not obvious to me what should i do. I want to understand the big picture. How things are wired.

What should i have inside my `Html.Attributes.src` function ?

I blindly tried many things. None of them worked. I lack the intuition.

**Can somebody please provide a clear implementation of how this `elm image/assets loading` actually works in `webpack 2`? Thanks :)**

Comment: "I've seen elmAssetsLoader and fileLoader custom functions mentioned inside the docks" : Which custom functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also tried placing the elm-assets-loader before and after the elm--webpack-loader

elm-assets-loader takes the output of elm-webpack-loader and looks for asset paths in the compiled JavaScript. As webpack applies loaders in the `use` config [from bottom to top](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-use), you want something like

```
use: [{
        loader: 'elm-hot-loader'
    },
    {
        loader: 'elm-assets-loader?module=MyAssets&tagger=AssetPath'
    },
    {
        loader: 'elm-webpack-loader?verbose=true&warn=true&debug=true'
    },
]
```

> And when i place it before elm-webpack-loader absolutely nothing happens. Not even a warning message.

This could be from not specifying the correct `package` in the loader config. If your `elm-package.json`'s `repository` is something that is ***not*** `"https://github.com/user/project.git"`, you need to specify the package:

```
// when the repository is "https://github.com/alon/elmapp.git"
loader: 'elm-assets-loader?module=MyAssets&tagger=AssetPath&package=alon/elmapp'
```

This is needed because elm-assets-loader looks for JavaScript code that looks like:

```
_<package-user>$<package-project>$<module>$<tagger>("../static/img/elm.jpg")
```

and if the package isn't correctly configured, it fails to find what it's supposed to find.

> img [ src "what to put in here?" ] []

You need a helper function to pull out the string value contained in the `AssetPath` variable.

```
module MyAssets exposing(AssetPath(..), path, elmImage)

path : AssetPath -> String
path (AssetPath str) =
    str

-- 

view = 
    img [ src <| MyAssets.path <| MyAssets.elmImage ] []
```

Comment: awesome answer. i didn't expect `elm-package.json` to have anything to do with my `webpack` configuration  - but makes so much sense the way you explain it. Thank you ! :smile:

Comment: One thing to note is that you can't have dynamic require, ie. `AssetPath (record.imagePath)`. There has to be static string in the argument of `AssetPath`.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply copy these images with [Copy Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin). In your webpack config plugins list push this:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    from: '',
    to: ''
})
```

Another way is to manage images from CSS and use file-loader:

```
{
   test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
   use: `file-loader?${ objToUrlParameters({

          name: 'assets/img/[name].[hash:6].[ext]',
          publicPath: options.publicPath

        })
      }`
},
```

Comment: thanks:) i posted same stuff without noticing your answer. As said - i expect a loader solution because it's the recommended way to do this sort of things in webpack - it also doesn't have async / dynamic fetching limitations :)

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using `CopyWebpackPlugin` [from here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin).

```
 plugins: [ 
    ...
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
       { from: './src/static/img', to: 'img' }
    ])
 ]
```

I doesn't work with async stuff form what i've read - but is good enough for what i needed here.

I will wait for another answer to mark it as accepted - if it can provide a solution using a loader. Until then, folks having this issue can try using this copy plugin.